# Magento table defenition

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, associated-products

Magento has this db table: `catalog_product_link_attribute`. What is the purpose of this table. I researched some and it relates to associated products. Who has some examples to advanced use of this feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table `catalog_product_link_attribute` is used to store attributes for product relations.
For example when adding a product as an upsell for an other one, you also fill in a 'poistion' field. in order for Magento to allow you to fill in that field it must exist in the table `catalog_product_link_attribute`.

The product relations are kept in `catalog_product_link`, but only as references to the ids of the products. (product_id, 'related_id' and 'relation_type'). The rest of the values are kept in the tables:

1. catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal
2. catalog_product_link_attribute_int
3. catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar

that have a reference to the `catalog_product_link_attribute` table. It's an EAV approach, somehow similar to how the products & categories are stored in the database, but on a smaller scale.

Comment: Yes, I also found this answer when I researched issue. Thanks